# when using "NPM install " to my ionic app, it gives such error , which has almost no reference in stackoverflow or github. I have no clue, what to do

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

> npm WARN tarball tarball data for igniteui-cli@4.2.4
> (sha512-jVspYOn9TmzxIbfkpw6TEVbGJeZXLWHWJfQcpd9qcRXpvrnwMqBnBrP7x/CX01NiXlpYey1xxa5PMn3Eu+OYDw==)
> seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
>
> npm WARN tarball tarball data for igniteui-cli@4.2.4
> (sha512-jVspYOn9TmzxIbfkpw6TEVbGJeZXLWHWJfQcpd9qcRXpvrnwMqBnBrP7x/CX01NiXlpYey1xxa5PMn3Eu+OYDw==)
> seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

Getting this error like it is in a loop... Uhhh

Here is the debug log..

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ 1 verbose cli
> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe', 1 verbose cli
> 'C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
> 1 verbose cli   'start' 1 verbose cli ] 2 info using npm@6.14.2 3 info
> using node@v12.16.1 4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start',
> 'poststart' ] 5 info lifecycle privet@0.0.1~prestart: privet@0.0.1 6
> info lifecycle privet@0.0.1~start: privet@0.0.1 7 verbose lifecycle
> privet@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true 8 verbose lifecycle
> privet@0.0.1~start: PATH:
> C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;I:\Pri-Vet\PriVet_App\node_modules.bin;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Common
> Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
> Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
> Files\Git\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\Gradle\gradle-4.6\bin;C:\composer;C:\Program
> Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS
> Code\bin;C:\Program
> Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
> Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Rakesh.windows-build-tools\python27;C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules.bin;C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.bin;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Common
> Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
> Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
> Files\Git\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\Gradle\gradle-4.6\bin;C:\composer;C:\Program
> Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS
> Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program
> Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Rakesh.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Rakesh\App;C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft
> VS Code\bin 9 verbose lifecycle privet@0.0.1~start: CWD:
> I:\Pri-Vet\PriVet_App 10 silly lifecycle privet@0.0.1~start: Args: [
> '/d /s /c', 'ionic serve' ] 11 silly lifecycle privet@0.0.1~start:
> Returned: code: 1  signal: null 12 info lifecycle privet@0.0.1~start:
> Failed to exec start script 13 verbose stack Error: privet@0.0.1
> start: `ionic serve` 13 verbose stack Exit status 1 13 verbose stack
> at EventEmitter.
> (C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20) 13
> verbose stack     at ChildProcess.
> (C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20) 13
> verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16) 13
> verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:286:5) 14 verbose pkgid privet@0.0.1 15
> verbose cwd I:\Pri-Vet\PriVet_App 16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134 17
> verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
> "C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
> "start" 18 verbose node v12.16.1 19 verbose npm  v6.14.2 20 error code
> ELIFECYCLE 21 error errno 1 22 error privet@0.0.1 start: `ionic serve`
> 22 error Exit status 1 23 error Failed at the privet@0.0.1 start
> script. 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
> likely additional logging output above. 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: I think the hash is not matching for this version;

Comment: So, what should I do? If you will tell in brief, it would be a great help to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove this dependency and add again or if you can manually add correct sha in package.json

Comment: npm uninstall igniteui-cli@4.2.4 

then

npm install igniteui-cli@4.2.4